# Other answers shown as "0)" when there is 1?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

First of all, I got this item to review – six days after it was deleted. So, I presume this was an audit? I didn't get a "Congratulations" message telling me I passed the audit, and even if I had gotten it, this would have been weird since I'm a mod, but … anyway.

See the "other answers" number here? `0)`? What is that supposed to mean?

[image]

In fact, the question [has exactly one other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/139334/iphone-3g-backup-encryption-ive-never-entered-a-password) (or should have had one if this item hadn't been deleted at the time I reviewed it).

---

Fun fact: It was *me* who had deleted the post on January 23. So why show me this as an audit?

[image]

Comment: The parenthesis also shows up on the late answers review; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165207/number-of-other-answers-in-the-late-answers-review-page-has-spurious-right-paren