# Number of other answers in the late answers review page has spurious right parenthesis

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, late-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Other answers shown as “0)” when there is 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165148/other-answers-shown-as-0-when-there-is-1)

I just noticed that on the Late Answers review page, the number of other answers displayed next to the answer being reviewed has a spurious right parenthesis after it.  Here's an example from [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/4948).

[image]

So far I've seen this behavior on Stack Overflow, Home Improvement, SciFi & Fantasy and Gardening & Landscaping, so I'm guessing it's site-wide.  I haven't seen it on any of the other review pages.

Comment: the supposed dupe is complaining the count is wrong. This one is about the excess ) which I have to say is more offputting than you would think. Perhaps random pseudo-typos are being introduced to make reviewers slow down and pay attention :-)