# Extra right parenthesis in mobile version of user-badge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, mobile-web

A very minor bug.

In the **mobile** version of [the "*user* earned this badge *n* times" page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=22656), there's an extra right parenthesis.

[image]

No such problem on the **full site**.

[image]

I also checked similar pages for a few other users/badges and the right parenthesis appears consistently.

*Sort of similar to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165207/204869)?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. One extra close paren in there.

A surgical strike to remove it has been successful. No other casualties.